# how to add area tags dynamically to map tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to load image dynamically and add an map tag to that image dynamically.
Also whatever the coordinates of different areas( suppose circle coordinates) are coming from database, I need to add those areas to map tag dynamically using loop in javascript/jquery may be.

I heard about addElement/ appendChild() method. But how to do that I dont know about it.

Any code implementing this functionality will be appreciated.

I need help regarding how to use addElement/appendChild() method to add area tags to map tag dynamically.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the solution by using JQuery we can add area tag dynamically and set attributes dynamically.

```
jQuery('<area/>', {
        id: $i,
        "class": 'some-class',
        coords : coords1,   
        "href" : 'abc.html',
    }).appendTo('#mymap');
```

Put the above code in loop and set change coords accordingly.